Track a "streak" for sequential records based on name, date and status
In Google Sheets, I would like to create a numerical column which tracks the "streak" of sequential records. This would be person-specific based on a name column, whether or not the records are sequential would be determined by a date column, and whether or not the streak is added to would be based on a status column. The contents of the status column are either "Complete", in which case the streak should be added to +1, or "Failed", in which case the streak should be reset to 0.
Example where the Streak column is what I am looking to automate with formula:



Date
Name
Status
Streak




21/10/2024
John
Approved
1


21/10/2024
Joe
Approved
1


22/10/2024
Jamie
Rejected
0


22/10/2024
Jay
Approved
1


22/10/2024
Joe
Approved
2


22/10/2024
Joe
Rejected
0


22/10/2024
Jamie
Approved
1


22/10/2024
John
Approved
2


22/10/2024
John
Approved
3


22/10/2024
Joe
Approved
1


23/10/2024
Jay
Approved
2


23/10/2024
Joe
Rejected
0


23/10/2024
Joe
Approved
1


23/10/2024
Jamie
Approved
2


23/10/2024
Joe
Approved
2


23/10/2024
Jamie
Rejected
0


23/10/2024
Joe
Approved
3


24/10/2024
Jay
Approved
3


24/10/2024
Jay
Approved
4


24/10/2024
Joe
Rejected
0



I have tried looking up similar issues and modifying those formulas with no success, as the only results I have found seem to involve grid arrays whereas I am looking to create a column which tracks a streak.


You may try:
=map(B2:B,C2:C,lambda(Σ,Λ,if(Σ="",,reduce(,filter(C2:Λ,B2:Σ=Σ),lambda(a,c,if(c="Rejected",0,a+1))))))


